# Solr - Difference Between Delta Query , Updation and Deletion?

Tags: solr

I want to understand the difference between Delta Update , Updation and Deletion in Solr .

Delta Query : What happens if the unique id during a delta query is same as an existing document's unique id ? I want to know if delta query can be used to both update and insert new records . Is the expected behaviour in this scenario to delete the old document and re insert the updated document with same unique id ? ( My unique Id is a template formed with the primary key of the entity in DB) .

Update - If I update with no records but just mention the document ID in the syntax , will that be equivalent to a delete since , updation happens through a delete followed by a fresh insert at the same unique id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delta Query basically will allow you to index documents incrementally.
Documents added after the last successful build time are the only one that would be included for Indexing.
Solr performs an update if the Document id already exists in the index.
Solr does not perform an actual update, but performs an delete and insert of the document
If the Document does not exist, its an insert by Solr.

If you update a Document with just the ID, it will overwrite the other fields.
However, this is not equivalent to Delete, cause the Document still exists in the Index with just the Id.
You should perform a delete to completely remove the document from the Solr Index.